# How would I resume and pause this thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-notifications

I am working with android development. I have a thread that I would like to resume or stop depending on a button push, but I do not know why my thread will not resume... 
Here is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Thread clientThread;

Boolean running = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    clientThread = new Thread(new Client());
    clientThread.start();

}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
class Client implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() 
    { 
      try {
          while (running == true) {

          //get sensor data here

          if (fsensor3 > 200) 
          {
              running = false; //To stop thread from repeating
              new MyVoltageAlert().execute(fsensor3);
              //What do I do here?
          }

          runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
          {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                  //UI stuff here

              }
          });
          }

      }
      catch(Exception e){

          e.printStackTrace();
      }

    }


}//End Client Thread

class MyVoltageAlert extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Integer>{

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params){
        return params[0];
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

        builder.setMessage(result + "mv")
        .setTitle("Sensor Warning!");
        // Add the buttons
        builder.setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //What do I do here?
                        // running = true;
                }
            });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Stop", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //What do I do here? 
                        // running = false;
                }
            });

     // Create the AlertDialog
     AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
     dialog.show();
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is that when the notification pops up and asks the user to stop or continue, the thread no longer runs even if running is set to true again. I know the thread cannot wait on the notification window, but why is it that when the user sets the value of running to true, does the code not run again?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to change to volatile Boolean running = true;

Comment: I changed it, but when I click continue on the notification the thread still does not run again.

Comment: you don't need have to use clientThread the MyVoltageAlert is one type of Background Thread.

Comment: @Dixit Patel So if I move the stuff from the clientThread into the doInBackground method in MyVoltageAlert I will be able to pause and resume my thread with the same logic?

Comment: @user3166938 Sorry, my suggestion is a general suggestion when using variables acessed from more than 1 thread..

Comment: @Seraphim It's okay, I appreciate any help I can get. You taught me something new today.

Comment: @user3166938 Good! We tend to underestimate very important aspects when working with threads for the first time...

Answer (score 0):

Look at these codes:

```
if (fsensor3 > 200) 
      {
          running = false; //To stop thread from repeating
          new MyVoltageAlert().execute(fsensor3);
          //What do I do here?
      }
```

maybe the reason for your problem is that, running is set to false again by the logic above.

Comment: If I do not set it to false, then the loop keeps running and I get multiple notifications, once I set it to false, it stops the loop from running again. I just do not know how to get the thread to repeat after this is set to false.